# Reactjs/Flux/altjs Listen for Store Changes slow down app

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux, reactjs-native, alt.js

i need to update Store on every button click on listView and change button state icon accordingly. unfollowing_ids is an array.

```
componentWillMount: function() {
 FollowingStore.listen(this.onChange);
 },

componentWillUnmount: function() {

FollowingStore.unlisten(this.onChange);
},
onChange: function(state) {
 this.setState({unfollowing_ids: state.unfollowing_ids});
},
```

what is the efficient way to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Solution that i found. Do not listen for store if you don't need it. I updates store on every button click and update local array.So local array and store array are getting sync and finally on returning back from another screen I just get `FollwingStore.getState().unfollowing_array` and  removes those items in `componentDidMount()` Method. This works for me. Any other suggestion would be appreciated.

Cheers